# Typescript Error: Property 'append' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript2.2

### The Problem:

I'm receiving a Typescript 2.2.1 compilation error when trying to append a compiled angular 1.5 template to an existing `HTMLElement`.

**Code:**

```
$document.find(scope.target)[0].append($compile(menu)(scope)[0]);
```

**Compile error:**

```
[ts] Property 'append' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

I've searched through the type definitions and don't see a signature for `append()`.

Any ideas as to which type or version of typescript I should be using?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `appendChild`? `append` is experimental and not on all browsers.

Comment: @AndrewLi No, not yet.  I'm converting existing working .js code into typescript.  So, I was hoping I wouldn't have to change any internals and could just create the typescript "container".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here there is nothing to do with TypeScript.

The correct method to call is `appendChild`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

`append` is a jQuery method, and if you want to use that you could do:

`$document.find(scope.target).append($compile(menu)(scope)[0]);`

and it should work too.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There is an append/prepend function on HTMLElement. The problem that it is [currently still experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).

In order to use it without getting errors from TypeScript I used it as any ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

`(<any>myElement).append(otherElement)`

Comment: This is a good solution. Better syntax would be:
`(myElement as any).append(otherElement)`

Answer (score 0):

[Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) now exists (since 2016). If TypeScript is finding an error:

- Types: ensure that it's an `Element` and not just a `Node`
- Config: ensure you're loading the DOM library
- Config: ensure you're using a recent ES target/lib

Example config:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2019", "es2020", "dom.iterable"]
  }
}
```